# Intercept of a Line problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

How would one find the x-intercept and y-intercept of the line with the equation $x-2y=0$?

Comment: But how can I actually plot the graph of L?

Comment: When the line crosses the x-axis, $y = 0,$  When $y = 0 \rightarrow x = 0$. When the line crosses the y-axis, $x=0$, and $x=0 \rightarrow y=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The $x$ intercept occurs when $y=0$.

The $y$ intercept occurs when $x=0$.

Can you proceed?

Answer (score 3):

**Finding intercepts**

The $x$ intercept of a line is the point on the line (if it exists) at which the y-coordinate is $0$. Thus to find this point we just set $y = 0$ in the equation of the line:
$$
x - 2(0) = 0\\
\Rightarrow x = 0
$$

Hence the $x$-coordinate of the $x$-intercept is $0$. See if you can figure out how to find the $y$-coordinate of the $x$-intercept.

**Finding the slope**

The slope of a line can be found if we know two points which lie on the line. If we first find the $y$-intercept and call it $(x_1, y_1)$ and then the $x$-intercept and call it $(x_2, y_2)$, then the slope is given by
$$
m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
$$